# Search multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following multidimensional array.

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'title1',
        'url' => 'http://www.foo.bar/',
        'blurb' => 'blurb1',
        'custodian' => 'custodia1',
        'tags' => 'tag1',
        'active' => 'Y',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'title' => 'title2',
        'url' => 'http://www.foo.bar/',
        'blurb' => 'blurb2',
        'custodian' => 'custodia2',
        'tags' => 'tag1,tag2',
        'active' => 'Y',
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'title' => 'title3',
        'url' => 'http://www.foo.bar/',
        'blurb' => 'blurb3',
        'custodian' => 'custodia3',
        'tags' => 'tag1,tag2,tag3',
        'active' => 'Y',
    ),
);
```

I need to filter the array so that only the arrays with "tag2" in the tags value are displayed.

I've looked at `array_filter` but just can't get my head around it.

Here is my attempt but it doesn't work at all. not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$filterArr = array_filter($arr, function($tag) {

   return ($tag['tags'] == 'tag2');

});
```

Comment: what's the data source?

Comment: show us what you've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use foreach loop and in the body of loop check for 'tag2'

If you need to delete all rows without tag2 in tags you can use next loop:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (!preg_match('/\btag2\b/',$value['tags'])) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

array_filter takes each element of the array and passes it to the specified function, in that function you need to return true or false, true if it should stay in and false if it should be filtered out

Use `explode` and `in_array` to check for tag2

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($arr, "filterTag");

function filterTag($arrayElement) {
   return in_array("tag2",explode(",",$arrayElement["tags"]));
}
```

your attempt does not work because some of your "tags" contain other words than `tags2`, like `tag1,tag2,tag3` doing a simple `==` comparison does not search a string for another string

Answer (score 2):

you could use array_filter and provide the right callback

```
$result = array_filter($arr,function($t){
    return in_array('tag2',explode(',',$t['tags']));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$resultArr = array();
foreach($arr as $curr)
{

$tagsData = explode(',',$curr['tags']);
if(in_array('tag1',$tagsData)
   $resultArr[] = $curr;



}
```

$resultArr is the resulting array containing the arrays with tags having tag1